# PHPMailer timing out google chrome page when loading

Tags: php, phpmailer

So I have PHPMailer setup correctly, I have the message with the unique parts all set up with PHP.

At the moment, I just have a PHP webpage, which firsts retrieves all the emails it needs from the database before it goes through each email and sends it. Unfouratenly when I tried to give the database 30 emails, I went to the php file in chrome, and it was just white for a couple of minutes before I eventually got the timeout message on chrome. At the moment I have no idea how many emails got sent, but what I am asking is how can I send all the emails on the page whilst not causing the page to become time out

Here is a quick overview on my flow

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Maketting</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
require "../api/access.php";
require "../api/api.php";


echo "<h1>Please wait....</h1>";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `Points` WHERE `points` >='10'";
$result = sqlStatment($sql);
$emails = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $Name = $row['name'];

    $email = "null";
    $sqlnew = "SELECT `Student Email`  FROM `Orders` WHERE `Student UID` = '".$row['uid']."' LIMIT 0,1";

    $resultnew =  sqlStatment($sqlnew);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultnew)) {
          $email=$row['Student Email'];

        }
   array_push($emails, array("name" => $Name,"email" =>  $email));
}
?>
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Date and time</th>
        <th>User Name</th>


    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    <?
    $last = count($emails) - 1;

    foreach ($emails as $i => $row)
    {
        $isFirst = ($i == 0);
        $isLast = ($i == $last);
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";


        echo "</tr>";
    }



?>
    </tbody>
</table>
    <?php


    require '../mail/load.php';
    $last = count($emails) - 1;
    foreach ($emails as $i => $row) {
        $isFirst = ($i == 0);
        $isLast = ($i == $last);

        $name = $row['name'];
        $email = $row['email'];
        if (!$email = "n/a") {

            $mail = new PHPMailer;

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

            $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
            $mail->Host = '';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
            $mail->Username = '';                 // SMTP username
            $mail->Password = '';                           // SMTP password
            $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
            $mail->Port = 25;                                    // TCP port to connect to

            $mail->setFrom('', 
            $mail->addAddress($email, $name);     // Add a recipient
            // Name is optional
            $mail->addReplyTo('', '');


            // Optional name
            $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

            $mail->Subject = '';
            $mail->Body = '


        ';
            $mail->AltBody = 'Hi there,


';

            if (!$mail->send()) {
                echo 'Message could not be sent.';
                echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
            } else {
                echo "<br>Email Sent to " . $name . "<br>";
            }

        }
    }

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is something i would push in to the background, no need for a browser to just sit there

Comment: @Dagon Could you show me a place to learn how to push it in the background? I have learnt everything I know about PHP from just tutorials and stackoverflow and have no idea.

Comment: `exec("php send_email.php  > /dev/null &");   `

Comment: @Dagon Where do I put that? In Cron Jobs?

Comment: no its php, you could run this as a cron job if you wanted then it would just be `php send_email.php`

Answer (score 0):

You're sending very inefficiently, creating a PHPMailer instance every time around the sending loop, and that means you can't use keepalive. Take a look at [the mailing list example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps) for how to send more efficiently. Aside from that, as the others have said, run this as a cron job. You could also make it go faster by running a local mail server as submitting to that will be much quicker and let the mail server deal with slow delivery to the destination. This will also deal with delivery deferrals (retries), timeouts, bad connections, bounces etc.